# paths in tsconfig cannot import the type

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, tsconfig, type-declaration

I'm working on server side project using TypeScript.
And I defined some types in ooo.d.ts. And I set `paths` in `tsconfig.json`.
But When I try to import the type I defined, It shows the error, `Module '"../../@types/express-custom-types"' has no exported member 'CustomError'.`

The project structure is like the below.

```
├── src
│   └── routes
│       └── errorHandlers.ts
├── tsconfig.json
└── @types
    └── express-custom-types
        └── index.d.ts
```

I define the types in `index.d.ts` like the below.

```
declare module "express-custom-types" {
  export type ErrorBody = { type: string; status: number; message: string };
}
```

And I defined alias in tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...(omit)...

    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["*"],
      "@custom-types/*": ["@types/*"],
    },
```

And import the type in `errorHandlers.ts` like this.

```
import { ErrorBody } from "@custom-types/express-custom-types";
```

But it shows error `Module '"../../@types/express-custom-types"' has no exported member 'ErrorBody'.`

I don't know what to do..

Comment: Remove `declare module "express-custom-types"` wrapper. Why do you need it? There's no such a module I guess

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thank you very much. This works for me :)
Then When should I use `declare module` syntax? Btw, plz write your comment as an answer, then I'll take it.

Comment: Added a bit more info in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`declare module ...` can be used to add or augment declarations of some external module (usually installed through `package.json` or generated during the "build").

But this is not the case here, the file/module is part of the project and you can just remove `declare module "express-custom-types"` wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure that the module you're declaring has the same full name as the one you're trying to import. This should work:

```js
declare module "@custom-types/express-custom-types" {
  export type ErrorBody = { type: string; status: number; message: string };
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to let you guys know my tsconfig.json setting. 
`"paths": {
      "@custom-types/*": ["@types/*"],
    }`
But now, the comment on my question resolved it. Thanks anyway :)